# XSL sort on content from several nodes

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have this XML-file  (irrelevant nodes left out) I need to sort.
Sorting should be on author when there is an author.
If the same author has written more books his/her books should be sorted on title. If author is missing sorting should be on first word in title. 
Desired order is: Lacey, Minna - New advanced teaching methods - Tekniska museet - Wrede, Eva: Arton kvadrat - Wrede, Eva: Femton kvadrat.

Authors can have either MarcEntry tag 100 or MarcEntry tag110, but not both. There are records without an author. All records have a title = MarcEntry tag 245.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="gallring2.xsl"?>
<report>
<catalog>
  <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Wrede, Eva</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Arton kvadrat</marcEntry>
  </marc>
  <call>
    <item>
      <itemID>3058000817845</itemID>
    </item>
  </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
  <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Wrede, Eva</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">Femton kvadrat</marcEntry>
  </marc>
  <call>
    <item>
      <itemID>30580008156593</itemID>
    </item>
  </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
  <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="110" label="Corporate Author" ind="2 ">Tekniska museet</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">35 mer eller mindre märkliga föremål i Tekniska museets samlingar</marcEntry>
  </marc>
  <call>
    <item>
      <itemID>30580008290806</itemID>
    </item>
  </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
  <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="100" label="Personal Author" ind="1 ">Lacey, Minna</marcEntry>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">365 experiment för nyfikna barn</marcEntry>
  </marc>
  <call>
    <item>
      <itemID>30580009824363</itemID>
    </item>
  </call>
</catalog>
<catalog>
  <marc>
    <marcEntry tag="245" label="Title" ind="10">New advanced teaching methods.</marcEntry>
  </marc>
  <call>
    <item>
      <itemID>30580008182334</itemID>
    </item>
  </call>
</catalog>
</report>
```

I tried this in my stylesheet

```
<xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110']"/>
```

but that just gave me errors and would only have been half-way, had it worked.

Any suggestions on how to continue? XSLT 2.0 and extensions are not an option.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <catalog>
        <xsl:for-each select="report/catalog/call/item">

            <xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100']"/>
            <xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='245']"/>

                        <itemline>
                            <Author><xsl:value-of select="substring(../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110'],1,30)"/></Author>
                            <Title><xsl:value-of select="substring(../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='245'],1,30)"/></Title>
                            <itemID><xsl:value-of select="itemID"/></itemID>
                        </itemline>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </catalog>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The expression `<xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110']"/>` is valid. What errors did you get when you used it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (single) sort expression

```
<xsl:sort select="normalize-space(concat(../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110'], ' ', ../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='245']))"/>
```

But this would have a problem if you had an author called "Ivor Evans" who wrote a book called "Jones The Steam", and another author called "Ivor Evans Jones" who wrote a book called "The Steam".

Instead, try these two expressions:

```
<xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110'] | ../../marc[not(marcEntry[@tag='100' or @tag='110'])]/marcEntry[@tag='245']"/>
<xsl:sort select="../../marc/marcEntry[@tag='245']"/>
```

Comment: Excellent - it works better than the deliverad stylesheets from a worldleading company with 5000+ customers!